# Jquery roundslider with angular 6

Tags: angular

I have import Jquery roundslider in my Angular 6 application but it's show following error.

> jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__(...).roundSlider is not a
>   function.

I have followed this link: [How to use RoundSliderUI in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52680272/how-to-use-roundsliderui-in-angular-6)

But still I am facing this issue.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you have any success yet?

Comment: @MartinCremer just check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yabjjf

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. My mistake was that in the files where i needed it i imported it like this

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

It all worked fine when i changed that to

```
declare const $: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Install jQuery:`npm install jquery --save`

Install typings for jQuery: `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`

Install RoundSliderUI: `npm i round-slider see npm round-slider`

In tsconfig.app.json add jQuery under types; the result for me looks like this:

```
    {  
      "extends": "../tsconfig.json",  
      "compilerOptions": {  
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",  
        "types": [ 
          "jquery"  
         ]  
     },   
      "exclude": [  
        "src/test.ts",  
        "**/*.spec.ts"  
      ]
     }
```

In angular.json add the path to the scripts:

```
    "scripts": [ 
      "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",   
      "./node_modules/round-slider/dist/roundslider.min.js"
     ]
```

Also add in angular.json the path to the css file under styles:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss",
  "./node_modules/round-slider/dist/roundslider.min.css"
 ]
```

In typings.d.ts add the following, if the file doesn't exist create it in the folder where the index.html is located as well.

```
interface JQuery {
   roundSlider(options?: any): any;
 }
```

Now check to include a slider anywhere </div

Comment: This didn't help me. And it doesn't seem to add anything new to the referenced answer.